# CI with Hudson and Cucumber

Tags: ruby, hudson, cucumber, bdd, hudson-plugins

I want to use Cucumber with Hudson CI. Is that possible to run cucumber features inside hudson without using JRuby?
If yes can you please provide some simple steps on how to setup the Hudson?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have cucumber installed on the server, you can test any application by executing cucumber as a build step.

See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Continuous-Integration for an example using Hudson (now called Jenkins).

Comment: @corroded, I fixed it. Evidently the author changed his name to cucumber :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Jenkins and the Rake plugin.
Then create a Rakefile. Here is an example that only runs cukes tagged with @jenkins

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'

require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new( :features) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features --tags @jenkins "
end
```

One thing to watch out for. If you are doing tests in IE in Windows then run 'services.msc', find the Jenkins service, and check the option to allow it screen access.